# Any eclipse plugin to edit web.xml in Java EE App?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I want a good plugin to edit web.xml descriptor in a Java EE Aplication, like the wizard of netbeans or jdeveloper.

anyone knows? I look for JBoss Tools but i have problems with the installation :(

Something like this;

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think Jboss tools should work if you look deeper into that install problem, but an independent alternative could be [WTP](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)